# Too many redirects for preferences page

Tags: bug, profile-page

Trying to open [user preferences page with id=0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/0) leads to “too many redirects”:

> [image]

Using exist but not equal to the current user id shows me a 404 page as expected.

Comment: You just typed that in the address bar  or is there a direct link that brought you there?

Comment: @rene I have changed only one digit in the address of my preferences just for curious, and were redirected to “0” page.

Comment: Okay, this needs better handling but isn't necessarily the highest prio. It needs to go to a 404 page.

Comment: @rene yep, I would like the same thing, but probably not cleared reflect it in my post. Feel free to edit it if you think this could make the question best.